# Config Flow to Create a Record A Using Record B Data and Reevaluate B Records to Associate Record A to Other B Records and Avoid Duplicating Record A

Tags: duplicate-management, visual-flows, data-synchronization

I have configured a complex flow for a data sync using an ingest file and mostly fast elements to update and create records. For context, I am working with a child object, contact role, to drive updates and creation on parent records, contacts.

I am running into a wall where I have multiple records in the ingest file that all refer to a parent record that doesn't exist in the target system.

Whats happening is that the flow evaluates all child records at once and creates duplicates of parent record.

What I would like is to build logic to create the parent record associated with the first child record evaluated, then reevaluate parent record table to retrieve the id of the recently created parent record and associate to the other child records instead of creating duplicate parent contact records each time I evaluate the child records.

Please help me think through which elements, filter fields, and logic I can use to accomplish this requirement. I am stumped having thought through design for fast and record lookups/creates using wait and decision elements.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and a friend who's running into the same issue, this a known issue in Salesforce. I changed configuration to account for match variables if already exists in Target System or recently created in Target System, but the flow gets confused, doesnt know which record to query and then doesn't create the first or any of the duplicate contact records...